# Print rdlc report without showing PrintDialog() in C#?

Tags: c#, reporting-services, printing, rdlc

I am developing a POS application for my client. I want to print the invoice. The computer has connected with 3 different printers. I have to print the invoice without showing the PrintDialog() to a specific printer that is not default printer. How to complete this task?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is this WinForms, WPF, or an ASP application?

Comment: MSDN has an example at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252091.aspx